# I want the taskbar to be visible & My Frame be maximized

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, taskbar

Snippet Of The code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // for fit to screen maximize
```

Just like in games, I don't want this to be resizable; at the same time I want to have the taskbar and titlebar visible (just like any application)

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is by extending the JFrame class and overriding the maximizing methods in order to reduce the frame size

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    private Rectangle maxBounds;
    
    public MyFrame()
    {
        super();        
        maxBounds = null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Rectangle getMaximizedBounds()
    {
        return maxBounds;
    }
    
    @Override
    public synchronized void setMaximizedBounds(Rectangle maxBounds)
    {
        this.maxBounds = maxBounds;
        super.setMaximizedBounds(maxBounds);
    }
    
    @Override
    public synchronized void setExtendedState(int state)
    {       
        if (maxBounds == null &&
            (state & Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
        {
            Insets screenInsets = getToolkit().getScreenInsets(getGraphicsConfiguration());         
            Rectangle screenSize = getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds();
            Rectangle maxBounds = new Rectangle(screenInsets.left + screenSize.x, 
                                        screenInsets.top + screenSize.y, 
                                        screenSize.x + screenSize.width - screenInsets.right - screenInsets.left,
                                        screenSize.y + screenSize.height - screenInsets.bottom - screenInsets.top);
            
            super.setMaximizedBounds(maxBounds);
        }
    
        super.setExtendedState(state);
    }
}
```

Then just instantiate the custom MyFrame class instead

```
MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setLayout(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: I am new to Java can you suggest any simpler code?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of your statements:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getSize());
```